# Configuring openstack for a in-house test cloud

Tags: openstack

We're currently looking to migrate an old and buggy eucalyptus cloud to openstack. We have ~15 machines that are all on the same office-internal network. The instances get their network configuration from an external (not eucalyptus) DHCP server. We run both linux and windows images. The cloud is used exclusively for platform testing from Jenkins.

Looking into openstack, it seems that out of the three supported networking modes, none really fit our environment. What we are looking for is something like an "unmanaged mode" where openstack launches an instance that is hooked up to eth0 interface on the instances' compute node and which will receive its network configuration from the external DHCP on boot. I.e. the VM's, guest hosts and clients (jenkins) are all on the same network, managed by an external DHCP server.

Is a scenario like this possible to set up in OpenStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not commonly used, but the Networking setup that will fit your needs the best is FlatNetworking (not FlatDHCPNetworking). There isn't stellar documentation on configuring that setup to work through your environment, and some pieces (like the nova-metadata service) may be a bit tricky to manage with it, but that should accomplish allowing you to run an OpenStack cloud with an external DHCP provider.

I wrote up the wiki page http://wiki.openstack.org/UnderstandingFlatNetworking some time ago to explain the setup of the various networks and how they operate with regards to NICs on hosting systems. FlatNetworking is effectively the same as FlatDHCPNetworking except that OpenStack doesn't try and run the DHCP service for you.

Note that with this mode, all the VM instances will be on the same network with your OpenStack infrastructure - there's no separation of networks at all.

Comment: I did a lot of experimenting with FlatNetworking last week, and as you mentioned the metadata service and nova-network routing didn't work very well and the documentation wasn't very helpful. I decided to use a private network and route access through the cloud controller instead. If it doesn't work once I start scaling with more nodes, I'll revisit flatnetworking again. Thanks for your answer!